# Products and pages won't load after setting up a new website in Magento

Tags: magento

I have created a new website in Magento Enterprise and also added existing products to it by updating the attributes in the manage products section.

The problem is that I am able to see the home page on the new website URL but when I navigate to products/pages, I get a 404.

I tried to add a new product in the system and noticed that it works fine on the other website I have but it won't appear on the newly created website. 
Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: add a debug.php file to the root of your magento with `<?php print_r(apache_get_modules()); ?>` in it (take care if you are using NGINX or Apache as cgi, this won't work...) Then check if **mod_rewrite** is present in the output. If not unable it on your apache. If you are on NGINX, check this link http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento , else well, then you have to tell us on what web server you are.

Comment: @Shoaib check other pages of the newly created website like cms pages.Are you getting  404 error on those pages also?

Comment: @Muk Yes, I am getting the same 404 for them too. It's so frustrating that the home page loads but the rest of the pages dont.

Answer (score 0):

Just found solution of my problem:

If your store is hosted on Ngnix server then you need to reindex again using SSH (provided you are using Magento Enterprise) because in Magento EE, they have disabled the reindex option in the admin panel.